# abstract syntax tree

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to fetch the following elements in the python code using Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)

1. List of classes in the python file
2. Under each class, I want to fetch the functions (def) available in it
3. Under each function, I want to fetch the function it is called from it

I tried with the following code, Still It seems so abstract and I am not able to find the best documentation for the Node definition in AST

```
data = open(test.py).read()
    return ast.parse(data, test.py)
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name):
            print(node.id)
```

I want a sample code which walk through the three possible cases in it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you're going to want to use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for this, not `ast`

Comment: 2. The name for a function in the context of a class is "method". 3. For that you will have to execute all possible paths in the code. Python has too many dynamic ways to execute a callable to derive this information from the AST.

Comment: @KlausD. Please let me some example for it please

Comment: @Jab Does inspect need the application to be up and running?

Comment: @jab Also, I see it is able to get the details of the functions in it but it is not able to tell which functions are called from the method.